# Foundation for apps: ng-disabled not working on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation-apps

I was using a [foundation for apps button](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/button) in a form. But **ng-disabled** isn't working with it.

**HTML:**

```
                 <form name="loginForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="grid-block">
                        <div class="grid-content">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="formData.username" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-block">
                        <div class="grid-content">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formData.password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-block">
                        <div class="grid-content">
                            <a class="button" type="button" href="#" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="userLogin()">Login</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{loginForm.$invalid}}
                </form>
```

When I use a normal HTML button it is working.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a button it's a link href, if you use a button tag it works fine.

```
<button class="button" type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="userLogin()">Login</button>
```

Comment: I know that. However, in foundation for apps buttons are in anchor tags. See the link: http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/button

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the same `button` class for a button tag instead an anchor and obtain the same result?

Comment: I can use it but it is not giving a disabled look to the button. Btw i am using ng-class={disabled: loginForm.$invalid}